# Find all JS classes used in web page

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find every unique class definition used in a WebPage? For example, if a web page has three unrelated JS classes `Dog`, `Cat,` and `Mouse`, but I do not know that these classes exist, how would I discover them?

```js
//returns all the JS classes in a document
function getAllDocumentClasses(){

}
```

This would be a function I would run in the chrome console.

Context: I'm preparing some documentation on extracting data from web pages using javascript. One approach to do this is to investigate the classes used in a library, for example, to see all the instances of a `Highcharts` and then extract the data used in that `Highcharts` instances. But if we do not know which libraries a web page is using, then this is more difficult.

Edit:
Seems like this might not be possible with javascript. But if you go to Chrome Developer Tools and type `window.`, then you can browse through available classes in the window.

[image: window]

Comment: If the classes are not in a scope you can access there is not much you can do to grab it unless you are writing some sort of spider that can find every JavaScript file/inline tag and somehow parses it to find classes.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out, a class names in Javascript don't have to be unique.  It's very possible to have multiple `Dog` classes, but them been totally different implementations..

Comment: Additionally, old-style classes (using constructor functions) are nigh indistinguishable from functions without inspecting instances, and, if the code is properly designed, most instances won't be visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to enumerate list of available classes in javascript es6](//stackoverflow.com/q/45709815/90527)", "[Javascript ES6 class definition not accessible in window global](//stackoverflow.com/q/37711603/90527)", "[Find all classes defined in scope of script](//stackoverflow.com/q/40561046/90527)"